# How do I use a Rotary Encoder to pick, a out a name from a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm a working on  a project where I'm using an raspberry pi zero to read and write to a google sheet using a RFID. It also has an LCD screen that shows your Chip id /name, classroom and datetime. It also includes a Rotary encoder.

This is my question.
How do I create a list or dictionary (don’t know what is best) where I can chose a from set list/dictionary a specific place. How would I print only y or x [x, y, x].

And how would I make the Rotary encoder be able to scroll the list/dictionary and then choose x, y or x

This is the code I have for the encoder: https://github.com/modmypi/Rotary-Encoder/

Comment: after looking at your code on github, are you using `counter` to keep track of the rotary encoder position? this should be fine I'm just trying to make sure I'm grasping what's going on

Comment: Please always include the code here in the question as a [mcve]. Links can break, or linked content can change (especially on github!) and that makes the question useless for anybody with similar problems. See also [ask].

Comment: if you would like to be able to navigate within directories to subdirectories & files etc as opposed to just navigating a list of files, you will use a dictionary with the directory names as `key` and their subdirectory structure as `value`. if  `value` is a subdirectory, `value` is also a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot missing in the question as far as requirements go, but here is an example that would achieve most of the functionality you've described so far:

```py
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep
# additional module for getting system information
import os

# create a list to populate with file names
options = []
# fill the list with the files in a specified directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('~/path/to/dir'):
    for file in files:
        options.append(file)
```

at this point you have a list with the names of the files you can choose between with your rotary encoder.. now we must add in the logic that you've already got on GitHub, with a few tweaks:

```py
max_index = len(options)-1
clk = 17
dt = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(clk, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(dt, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

counter = 0
clkLastState = GPIO.input(clk)

try:

        while True:
                clkState = GPIO.input(clk)
                dtState = GPIO.input(dt)
                if clkState != clkLastState:
                        if dtState != clkState:
                                counter += 1
                                if counter > max_index:
                                    counter = 0
                        else:
                                counter -= 1
                                if counter < 0:
                                    counter = max_index
                        print(counter)
                clkLastState = clkState
                sleep(0.01)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

---

**OR**

---

instead of checking the conditions after each change to counter, you could use make `counter` a modulus that uses the rotary encoder value over the length of the list of files, i.e.

```py
max_index = len(options)-1
clk = 17
dt = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(clk, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(dt, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

x = 0
clkLastState = GPIO.input(clk)

try:

        while True:
                clkState = GPIO.input(clk)
                dtState = GPIO.input(dt)
                if clkState != clkLastState:
                        if dtState != clkState:
                                x += 1
                                counter = x % len(options)
                        else:
                                x -= 1
                                counter = x % len(options
                        print(counter)
                clkLastState = clkState
                sleep(0.01)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```